# Even-odd program using bitwise

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, operators, bitwise-operators

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int n;

   printf("Input an integer\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   if (n & 1 == 0)
      printf("even\n");
   else
      printf("odd\n");

   return 0;
}
```

This program doesn't enter the If loop and always prints 'odd'. I understand that if(False) or if(0) is breaking condition but "n&1==0" is a TRUE condition for even numbers right? or am I missing something here?.

Comment: `(n & 1 == 0)` -> `((n & 1) == 0)`

Comment: Why you compare n&1 to 0 ?

Comment: @purec because if `n & 1` is zero, `n` is even.

Comment: i see now......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equality operators == and != have a higher priority than the bitwise AND operator.

So the condition in the if statements is equivalent to the following

```
if (n & ( 1 == 0 ) )
```

as 1 is not equal to 0 then the condition can be further rewritten like

```
if (n & 0)
```

Thus the substatement of the if statement is never executed because `n & 0` always evaluates to `false ( 0 )`.

To escape the logical mistake you could exchange the if and else statements.

```
   if (n & 1 )
      printf("odd\n");
   else
      printf("even\n");
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        int n;

        printf( "Input an integer (0 - exit): " );

        if ( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        printf( "%d is %s\n\n", n, n & 1 ? "odd" : "even" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Input an integer (0 - exit): 10
10 is even

Input an integer (0 - exit): 9
9 is odd

Input an integer (0 - exit): 8
8 is even

Input an integer (0 - exit): 7
7 is odd

Input an integer (0 - exit): 6
6 is even

Input an integer (0 - exit): 5
5 is odd

Input an integer (0 - exit): 4
4 is even

Input an integer (0 - exit): 3
3 is odd

Input an integer (0 - exit): 2
2 is even

Input an integer (0 - exit): 1
1 is odd

Input an integer (0 - exit): 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer I understand the logical error here. Can you also explain why u used  `scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1`  in your code as break condition?

Comment: @GaneshThampi The function scanf returns an integer that can be used to check whether scahf was successful. For example the user can interrupt the input pressing ctrl+Z in Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Enable all warnings in your compiler.  Mine says:

```
warning: & has lower precedence than ==; == will be evaluated first [-Wparentheses]
note: place parentheses around the & expression to evaluate it first
```

Answer (score 1):

`&` has a surprisingly low precedence so you need `(n & 1) == 0`. Better still, use

```
if (n & 1)
      printf("odd\n");
else
      printf("even\n");
```

Note that this is implementation defined for negative `int` values due to differing complementing schemes, so you may well not get a correct answer for a negative `n`. Perhaps use `unsigned`?

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to compare to zero. Any non zero value is the true, zero is false.

So it is enough to:

```
   if (n & 1 )
      printf("odd\n");
   else
      printf("even\n");
```

or

```
printf("%s\n", (n&1) ? "odd" : "even");
```